Is file pruning working only for filter and not join
I'm trying to optimize our way of work in the company.
Imagine that we have a very large table, bilions of rows.
This big table has a high cardinality column, let's say "id".
I have lots of data pipelines that every time wants to analyze only part of the ids, let's say that I have a dataframe of up to 100K ids which I want to specifically analyze.
Every time when I'm doing the initial inner join on the big table and small table of ids, I'm losing a lot of time and have poor performance.
It's also worth mentioning that I'm working in Databricks over deltalake.
My first idea to optimize this process was to z-order the big table by "id", then I was excepting that when I will join the big table with the small table on "id" I will enjoy the benefits of file pruning.
However it is seems that when I do joins even on the z-ordered column nothing happen and I always scan all the files.
So I conducted an experiment:
I created a big table:
sql_statement = """
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
    CAST(ABS(RAND() * 50000000) AS INT) AS id,
    CAST(ABS(RAND() * 40) AS INT) + 60 AS heart_rate 
FROM RANGE(1000000000)
)
SELECT id, CONCAT('Person ', id) AS name, heart_rate
FROM CTE
"""

Saved it as a table:
(spark.sql(sql_statement)
 .write
 .format("delta")
 .mode("overwrite")
 .save(<orig_table_path>)
 )

And created a copied table which is z-ordered:
(orig_table
 .write
 .format("delta")
 .mode("overwrite")
 .save(<opt_table_path>)
 )

import delta
(
    delta.DeltaTable.forPath(spark,<opt_table_path>)
    .optimize()
    .executeZOrderBy("id")
)

I created a dummy small ids dataframe that I want to join:
data = [Row(id=1000*i) for i in range(1,10)]

# Convert the list to a DataFrame
ids = spark.createDataFrame(data)

Then I tried two things:
First I tried to join opt_table with ids, in this experiment I got no file pruning at all.
Then I tired to filter ids as a list after collecting the ids dataframe:
opt_table_join.filter(F.col("id").isin(ids_list))

In this case everything worked great and I got excellent performance and pruning, which wasn't suprising.
I also enabled dynamicFilePruning but with no success.
Is there any configuration which will make spark prune files from the big table based on the rows from small table?
It seems weird to me that spark doesn't naturally examine the table in other side if the and evaluate id it can predicate push down filter based on the join column.
I thought in some point that this is the all idea of dynamic pruning but it seems that I missing something.
Is there a way to make spark prune based on the join column or I can get pruning only by using just filters?

You have answered your own question.
In SQL - Spark or otherwise - a JOIN is a separate operation to where the Filter occurs. From this slide courtesy of Purdue Univeristy - thanks - you can see the  various groupings of SQL based on Relational algebra.

The Filter is part of Unary Relations operations. JOIN is part of Set Theory operations.
The Optimizer in Spark - Catalyst - will not do an IN operation before hand to apply file / row, block pruning for data at rest. You need to add that to the SQL clause yourself - as you did. Why? Your case and dissussion is understandable, but RDBMS's can use indexes wheras Saprk processes using hashing for JOINing and Broadcasting and MERGEing. But, what if you have a three or 4 way JOIN against drivinbg table? It becomes more and more harder to generate the correct pruning logic. Spark does have a sub-select option now.
